# Java code reads file with unecognized signs

Tags: java, eclipse, readfile

I got a piece of code from online about reading excel file. But it prints out unrecognized signs. How do I print it out in the original format? Below is the printout:

\H�1��h�}�0vb��Yp� �k��G��
|8!�k�\r�q����H)Fd�i� �
4�0�Q���`��s�W&N���    �q�l)qt��m��ڴ��S��z|���t���L

The code is here:

```
package readText;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.BufferedReader;

public class fileData {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String file_name = "F:\\Testfile.xlsx";

        try{
            ReadFileLocal file = new ReadFileLocal(file_name);  
            String[] arylines = file.openFile();

            int i;
            for (i=0; i<arylines.length; i++){
                System.out.println(arylines[i]);
            }

        }
        catch(IOException e) 
            System.out.println(e.getMessage()); 
        }
    }
}


public class readFileLocal {
    private String path;

    public readFileLocal(String file_path){
        path = file_path;
    }

        int readLines() throws IOException{
            FileReader file_to_read = new FileReader(path);
            BufferedReader lines = new BufferedReader (file_to_read);

            int numberOfLines = 0;
            while((lines.readLine())!= null) { 
                numberOfLines ++; 
            }  

            lines.close();
            return numberOfLines;
        }

        public String[] openFile() throws IOException{ 
            FileReader freader = new FileReader (path); 
            BufferedReader textReader = new BufferedReader (freader);

            int numberOfLines = readLines();   
            String[] textData = new String[numberOfLines];

            int i;  
            for (i=0; i<numberOfLines; i++){
                textData[i] = textReader.readLine();  
        }

        textReader.close();
        return textData;
    }
```

Comment: Your code does not compile.

Comment: Excel does not use plain text files, but binary files which need a library to interpret the contents correctly.

Comment: Excel files are basically binary files, as they have a multi-layered architecture which the Excel program knows how to decode. If you're working with a strictly text file (CSV, for example), then the code should work (assuming you fix your errors...)

Answer (score 1):

You appear to be trying to read a binary file as text. You will need a specialized library to access the content of an excel file in Java.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Apache POI lib to read the excel files.

Comment: Thanks! I just started java. Will look up apache POI.